Is the stochastic integral process $\left(\int_{0}^{t}e^{-\lambda\left(t-s\right)}\mathrm{d}B_s\right)_{t\geq 0}$ a martingale?
Up to now, I was only presented with stochastic integral processes of the form $\left(\int_{0}^{t}\phi_s\mathrm{d}B_s\right)_{t\geq 0}$ and the general way to show that such a process is a martingale goes like this:

Show that $\phi$ is progressively measurable, e.g. by showing that $\phi$ is (a.s.) continuous and adapted.
Show that $\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^\infty \phi_s^2 \mathrm{d}s\right]<\infty$.


Let $\lambda>0$ and take $\left(\int_{0}^{t}e^{-\lambda s}\mathrm{d}B_s\right)_{t\geq 0}$ for example.
Define $\phi = (\phi_t)_{t\geq 0}$ by $\phi_t := e^{-\lambda t}$.

The process $\phi$ is deterministic and therefore adapted. We then have that $\phi$ is progressive since it is continuous and adapted.
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^\infty \phi_s^2 \mathrm{d}s\right] = \left[-\frac{1}{2\lambda} e^{-2\lambda s}\right]_{s=0}^{s=\infty} = \frac{1}{2\lambda} < \infty$$

It follows that the stochastic integral progress $\left(\int_{0}^{t} \phi_s \mathrm{d} B_s\right)_{t\geq 0}$ is a martingale.

Now let $\lambda>0$ and consider $\left(\int_{0}^{t}e^{-\lambda\left(t-s\right)}\mathrm{d}B_s\right)_{t\geq 0}$. The main problem here is that the integrand depends on $t$. I therefore can't solve it like above. If I try to drag $t$ out of the integrand, e.g. like
$$\int_{0}^{t}e^{-\lambda\left(t-s\right)}\mathrm{d}B_s = e^{-\lambda t}\int_{0}^{t}e^{\lambda s}\mathrm{d}B_s$$
then $\mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^\infty \phi_s^2 \mathrm{d}s\right]<\infty$ would no longer hold. I am confident that $\left(\int_{0}^{t}e^{-\lambda\left(t-s\right)}\mathrm{d}B_s\right)_{t\geq 0}$ is a martingale, but how can I show it?

The criterion you mentioned is certainly a sufficient condition, but not a necessary condition. So, let's go back to the basic.
Let $M_t = \int_{0}^{t} e^{-\lambda (t-s)} \, \mathrm{d}B_s$. Then for $0 \leq u \leq t$ and with the natural filtration $\mathcal{F}_t = \sigma(B_s : s \leq t)$,
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{E}[M_t \mid \mathcal{F}_u]
&= \mathbf{E}\biggl[ \int_{0}^{t} e^{-\lambda (t-s)} \, \mathrm{d}B_s \,\biggm|\, \mathcal{F}_u \biggr] \\
&= e^{-\lambda t} \mathbf{E}\biggl[ \int_{0}^{t} e^{\lambda s} \, \mathrm{d}B_s \,\biggm|\, \mathcal{F}_u \biggr] \\
&= e^{-\lambda t} \int_{0}^{u} e^{\lambda s} \, \mathrm{d}B_s \\
&= e^{-\lambda (t-u)} \int_{0}^{u} e^{-\lambda(u-s)} \, \mathrm{d}B_s \\
&= e^{-\lambda (t-u)} M_u.
\end{align*}
In the third step, we utilized the fact that $t\mapsto \int_{0}^{t} e^{\lambda s} \, \mathrm{d}B_s$ is a martingale.
Since $M_u$ is not identically zero (Why?), this implies that $(M_t)$ is not a martingale.

Can you please show that $\left(\int_0^t e^{\lambda s}\mathrm{d}B_s\right)_{t\geq 0}$ is a martingale?

Define $A_t := \int_0^t e^{\lambda s} dB_s$.  You are asking if $X_t := e^{-\lambda t} A_t$ is a martingale.  By Ito's formula, we have
\begin{align*}
dX_t &= e^{-\lambda t} dA_t -\lambda e^{-\lambda t} A_t dt \\
&= e^{-\lambda t} e^{\lambda t} dB_t - \lambda e^{-\lambda t} A_t dt \\
&= dB_t - \lambda e^{-\lambda t} A_t dt 
\end{align*}
Since the drift term $- \lambda e^{-\lambda t} A_t$ is not $0$, $X_t$ is not a local martingale, and hence also not a martingale.

Sorry, that should be $e^{-\lambda t} e^{\lambda t} dB_t = dB_t$.  It follows because $dA_t = e^{\lambda t} dB_t$ by definition.
